# Good at doing something (countable and uncountable nouns)

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-choice

I came across this question on a test:

> My friend is good at .... .
>
> a. making a cake.
> b. climbing a mountain
> c. making coffee
> d. writing
> reports

The answer is *c*, according to the answer key. It doesn't include any explanation.
I can't figure out why *d* is not correct. Is the question even correct?

Thanks

Comment: A bad test, created by an ignorant, lazy, fool. I hope you are not paying for the tuition from that source.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey fortunately not. It was in a test book. It's written by non-native speakers of English. As far as I know a and b are wrong cause they're countable nouns and we must use the plural form, when talking about them is general, as in making cakes and climbing mountains. But isn't it the same for writing reports? As you said it's just a bad test, I guess...

Comment: Answer (d) is fine.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey so is c, right?

Comment: c and d are fine, a and b should be "making cakes", "climbing mountains"

Comment: Sometimes singular is correct. I believe the similar sentence "My friend is good at riding a horse" is fine, perhaps because when you ride you only ride one horse.

Answer (score 1):

*Writing reports* is a skill not so easy to generalize as *climbing mountains* and *making cakes*. In the way it's presented on the test, answer **d** does not give much meaningful information without a qualifier.

*My friend is good at writing reports about geography.*